# Constraints tool for Blender 2.8

Tags: mesh, add-on, constraints

I am new in blender. Now I watch tutorials and try to make it. Have problem with making [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9L8qOq1Shiw) (He create a glass and destroy it with the bullet). To complete it I have to use the "Bullet Constraints Tools" (I need to tie the meshes so that they look like one object), but I can't find this or any kind like for Blender ver. 2.8. Here what I find: Bullet Constraints Tools, Bullet Constraints Builder.

[image]

Can I complete this tutorial without this tool, or there is another tool I can use that support Blender 2.8.

Comment: I'm actually doing the same course. I've been googling to see if maybe there is another version. Did you manage to find anything yet?

Comment: I found tutorial(https://youtu.be/l0tUkP3rGRw) about how to made constraint in 2.79 and then open this file in 2.8, but it didnt not work for me. I also found special constrait versiion of 2.8(https://blender.community/c/graphicall/Lcbbbc/), but it's non stable and closing after 2 minutes of working. I'm waiting of stable version of it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has now been ported to Blender 2.8.

https://github.com/timothy-strange/bullet-constraints-tool